# Ionic app doesn't install/emulate on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to test my ionic application as a native app on android.

I've tried running the command below as per the ionic documentation

ionic cordova run android

I've also connected up my phone and enabled USB debugging. I get a bunch of output but the app doesn't get installed onto my device.

I've also tried building the application for android but same error!!

```
cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:58469) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn EACCES
at _errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:499:9)
at Object.exports.spawn (/Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:134:31)
at GradleBuilder.runGradleWrapper (/Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:78:27)
at /Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js:177:21
at _fulfilled (/Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
at /Users/macbookpro/desktop/mobile/ionic/2018/vv/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:570:49
(node:58469) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:58469) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

[OK] Your app has been deployed.
     Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?
```

I have tried this:
1. Remove cordova android from my app 'ionic cordova platform rm android'
2. Add cordova-android 6.3.0 'ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0;'
3. Run: ionic cordova run android;

I have remeved node, ionic and cordova and install them from the beginning and still did'nt work.
ps: the problem always start when I add [Cordova AdMob Free plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob-free/)

Comment: I've solve it by deeply removing nodejs and all frameworks that related to it :)